# Website Architecture and programming language

Tags: backend, content-management-system

So I am starting this new business and I was wondering what are businesses and companies using for their website architecture.
I basically want to build a sample structure that I can replicate and deploy easily via API.

So the requirements for that would and correct me if I am wrong:

- A CMS
- A Database
- A Backend

My aim for this website is to be in synch with a central database that will be connected to the CMS, to a CRM or Contact Center and also to ecommerce to track transactions.
I want to be able to track and visualize as much data as possible being able to calculate for example precisely each call, picked up by which agent...

Be able to duplicate certain elements of the site and deploy them on other domains with different hostings.

I have read a lot online and there are a thousand setups, a lot with WP. I have nothing against it but I would like to know different setups easy to customize and deploy.

Thank you.

I am open for suggestions.